# Read a single attribute from an object - undefined

Tags: typescript

I can't get it to read a single attribute within an object. The following code gives me an undefined when I try to read the _id.

```
interface SINGLEUSER  {
 _id:string,
 name:string,
 email:string,
 image:string,
 emailVerified: any
}


console.log("UPDATE" )

const user_:SINGLEUSER = JSON.stringify(user) as unknown as SINGLEUSER

//Undefined
console.log(user_._id)

//Works
console.log(user_)

console.log(account!!.provider)

await User_.findOneAndUpdate({_id:user_._id },{provider: account!!.provider})

console.log("UPDATED" )
```

output:

> UPDATE
> undefined
> credentials
> UPDATED

But if i log just the whole user Object it shows the right:

```
{"_id":"645e2c7e31041f8404b8a260","name":"Max Mustermann ","email":"max.mustermann@t-online.com","image":"https://...","emailVerified":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify

```
const user_:SINGLEUSER = JSON.parse(user) as unknown as SINGLEUSER
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` transform an object into a string, so you cannot access the properties of the object unless you parse it with `JSON.parse`.

Why do you use `JSON.stringify` in the first place ?

Comment: Because the following doesn't work either:  console.log("USER: " +user._id)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

You can use classes as they works like types/interfaces in TS:

```
class SINGLEUSER {
 _id = '',
 name = '',
 email = '',
 image = '',
 emailVerified = false
}
```

Then you can create an object cleaner/parser function like this:

```
function clearParseObject<T>(C: any, o: any, f: any = {} ): T {
  Object.keys( C ).forEach( ( key: any ) => {

      const keyType = typeof C[ key ]
      const Value = o[ key ] ?? C[ key ] 

      if (
        !!Value &&
        keyType === 'object' &&
        Object.keys( Value ).length > 0
      ) {
        // if key is another object
        if ( !Array.isArray( Value ) ) {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], Value )
          return f
        }

        // if key is an array
        Value.forEach( ( itens: any ) => {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], itens, f[ key ] )
          return f
        } )
      }
      
      // assign the value to it's key
      f[ key ] = Value
    } )
    // return the new object cleared and typed
    return f as T
}
```

This function will loop for each key of the type class and get from the object only keys that exists in your type class, then creates a new object and return it typed.
You can use it like this:

```
const user: any = {
  name: 'John',
  _id: '123',
  email: 'abc@123',
  image: '',
  emailVerified: false,
  otherPropNotListed: 'anything'
}

const user_ = clearParseObject<SINGLEUSER>(new SINGLEUSER(), user)

console.log(`user id: ${user_._id}`) // logs '123'
console.log(`user otherPropNotListed: ${user_.otherPropNotListed}`) // logs undefined
```

Note that now `user_` variable is from type `SINGLEUSER` and if you try to get `otherPropNotListed` from it TS will show you an error because it does not exists on `SINGLEUSER` type.

This works for any Object you want to clear/type based on class without any TS error

[Here's a code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-pw5gn7)

Or, if you want, you can use a [simplified](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-simplified-iv056l?file=/demo.tsx) version too